# USB wifi dongle keeps disappearing/reappearing in device manager

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, device-manager

Windows 10 Education
TP-Link Archer T3U USB 3.0 AC1300 Mini Wireless MU-MIMO USB Adapter

My USB wifi dongle keeps disappearing/reappearing every few seconds in device manager. Of course I also lose my Internet connection each time this happens. Sometimes I can go days without this happening however. How do I troubleshoot this issue? Thanks.

Other devices attached to the same external USB hub:

- Logitech M510 wireless mouse (not bluetooth)
- ZEXMTE Bluetooth USB Adapter CSR 4.0 (not needed at the moment)

Other USB devices attached elsewhere:

- TOMOKO Water-Resistant Mechanical Keyboard
- Brother MFC-J825DW Printer

USB devices not currently attached:

- Logitech USB Camera (Pro 5000)
- Windows smartphone
- Android smartphone
- Several portable MP3 players
- Several video game controllers

Comment: What other USB devices do you have connected to the same USB Hub?  Instead of submitting commentary you should edit and clarify your question with the required information required to answer your question.

Comment: What happens if you connect the wifi stick directly to the mainboard (avoid front USB ports)? If possible without extension cable.

Comment: I did as you suggested. Now it's time to wait. It's not something that happens every day.